# Number of changes in common rows based on similar data point

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two queries. The first checks for any columns that change (FirstName, LastName, Phone) based on another column being the same (EncounterID):

```
 select FacilityCode, AdmitDate,
  sum(case when NumFirstName <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
  sum(case when NumLastName <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) as DifferentLastNames,
  sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) as DifferentPhone ,
  'Non-Defect' Label  

 from (select EncounterId, FacilityCode, AdmitDate, count(*) as Num,
  count(distinct left(FirstName,4)) as NumFirstName,
  count(distinct LastName) as NumLastName,
  count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone,

 from [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]

 group by EncounterId, facilitycode, AdmitDate
 ) e
 group by FacilityCode, AdmitDate;
```

The second checks for all instances where columns do not change:

```
 select FacilityCode, AdmitDate,
  sum(case when NumFirstName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
  sum(case when NumLastName <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentLastNames,
  sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPhone ,
  'Non-Defect' Label  

 from (select EncounterId, FacilityCode, AdmitDate, count(*) as Num,
  count(distinct left(FirstName,4)) as NumFirstName,
  count(distinct LastName) as NumLastName,
  count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone,

 from [BINextGen].[dbo].[tbFCCDefectReport]

 group by EncounterId, facilitycode, AdmitDate
 ) e
 group by FacilityCode, AdmitDate;
```

I have been able to manipulate the output to show me 'defect rates' for each facility and admit date (EncounterID is the identifier for a patient file and I am trying to see if any data in the file changes over time). Now I want to see how many EncounterIDs have ANY column change.  See example below:

```
FacilityCode    AdmitDate    EncounterID    FirstName    LastName    Phone 
SMAL            5/15/15      A01342         Justin       Kelley      5551212
SMAL            5/15/15      A01342         Justin       Kelly       5551212
SMAL            5/15/15      B53421         John         Doe         7771234
SMAL            5/15/15      B53421         John         Doe         7771234
```

Current Output:

```
FacilityCode    DifferentFirstNames    DifferentLastNames    DifferentPhone    Label
SMAL            2                      1                     2                 Non-Defect
SMAL            0                      1                     0                 Defect
```

Desired Output:

```
FacilityCode    Count    Label
SMAL            1        Defect
SMAL            1        Non-Defect
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case
WHen sum(case when NumFirstName <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) >= 1 Then  1 
 WHEN  sum(case when NumLastName <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) >= 1 Then  1 
 WHEN sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 0 else 1 end) >= 1 Then  1 
else  0 end as 'Count'
```

You just need to bundle your parameters into a case statement. 
Hope it helps. 
Also your code samples are duplicates, just an fyi

Comment: I also had to add EncounterID to the select clause and group by statement, but that did the trick. Thank you.